# JComponent name cannot be resolved, when used in another method

Tags: java, database, swing, oop

I'm following a youtube tutorial (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpbQ0DCFF0M) to populate a JCombobox called "comboAccountName" with a database table.
My database connection is setup in another class.

The code is as follows -

```
public class Execute extends JFrame {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;




//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


public Execute() 
{

.............other code...............
JComboBox comboAccountName = new JComboBox();
    comboAccountName.setBounds(313, 31, 302, 20);
    getContentPane().add(comboAccountName);

.............other code...............

}

void PopulateJCB()
{
    String queryString = "SELECT DISTINCT [Account Name] FROM main ORDER BY [Account Name]";
    try
    {

        Connection statJCBaccountname = DatabaseConnection.ConnectDB();
        Statement stmt = statJCBaccountname.createStatement();
        ResultSet rsJCBaccountname = stmt.executeQuery(queryString);

        while (rsJCBaccountname.next())
        {
            comboAccountName.addItem(rsJCBaccountname.getString(1));
            System.out.println(rsJCBaccountname.getString(1));
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Execute frame1 = new Execute();
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    PopulateJCB();

}
```

There are 2 errors where I'd like your help

```
comboAccountName cannot be
```

resolved

occurs inside the while loop, at following line

```
comboAccountName.addItem(rsJCBaccountname.getString(1));
```

AND

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method PopulateJCB() from the type
```

Execute

occurs when I'm trying to call PopulateJCB(); in the main method

I know the code in the tutorial video isn't exactly the same, but I'm trying to do a similar thing here. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scope! You declare your comboAccountName inside of the constructor and so it is visible only inside of the constructor. Try to use it elsewhere and it fails. Solution: declare it outside of the constructor on the class level.

So not:

```
public class Execute extends JFrame {

  public Execute() 
  {
    JComboBox comboAccountName = new JComboBox(); // this guy is visible only in here
    comboAccountName.setBounds(313, 31, 302, 20);  // don't do this!
    getContentPane().add(comboAccountName);
  }
```

but rather:

```
public class Execute extends JFrame {
  private JComboBox comboAccountName = new JComboBox();

  public Execute() 
  {
    comboAccountName.setBounds(313, 31, 302, 20);
    getContentPane().add(comboAccountName);
  }
```

---

Next we'll talk about your use of null layouts, `setBounds(...)` and absolute positioning. While to a newbie this seems the best way to create complex GUI's, the more you deal with Swing GUI creation, the more you will find that doing this will put your GUI in a straight-jacket, painting it in a very tight corner and making it very hard to extend or enhance. Just don't do this.

---

As for this error:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method PopulateJCB() from the type

You must create an instance of the class and call the method on the instance, not on the class itself.

So not:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub   // please clean your code of this before posting here
Execute frame1 = new Execute();
frame1.setVisible(true);
PopulateJCB();
```

but:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Execute frame1 = new Execute();
frame1.setVisible(true);
frame1.PopulateJCB(); // call it on the Execute instance, frame1
```

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks!!!  Sorry, I'm a beginner at Java, my source of learning is books, youtube and stackoverflow only

Comment: @Satnamxv63: see edit to answer. I do suggest though that you work through a beginner's Java book before trying to do Swing + database coding. You're climbing a very steep learning curve hill, and I think that you'd be far better off, and less likely to quit if you lower the slope of the hill a little bit.