# JPanel error - J Component cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jpanel

I've library of JRE System Library JRE 1.8.x
Here an error goes with my lines.

Error: The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

How can I remove this error? Here is screenshot: 
http://i60.tinypic.com/15z1n2h.png

[image]

Kindly tell me steps. I am new to Java. Thanks in advance.

.
.
**Package Snake**
**Class RenderPanel

```
package snake;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class RenderPanel extends JPanel{
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}
```

**Class Snake**

```
package snake;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Snake {

    public JFrame jframe; 

    public Toolkit toolkit;

    public static Snake snake;

    public Snake() {
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        jframe = new JFrame("Snake");
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.setSize(800,700);
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - jframe.getWidth() / 2, dim.height / 2 - jframe.getHeight() / 2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        snake = new Snake();
    }
}
```

Comment: For instance, please look at [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22002636/522444).

Comment: try to add `import javax.swing.JComponent;` otherwise your jdk is not on the classpath

Comment: Here are the errors Sir,

Line 7: Multiple markers at this line
 - The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
  required .class files
 - The hierarchy of the type RenderPanel is inconsistent



Line 12: The method paintComponent(Graphics) is undefined for the type JPanel

Comment: When I added import java.swing.JComponent; ------------ it gave error: "The import javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved"

Comment: same error with import javax.swing.JComponent;

Comment: Please check out the [help] as well as the [How Do I Ask Good Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see why this is important and what you can do to improve your question for us.

Comment: @DavidStevenson resuming all recommendations: **1)** Add your code to your question. **2)** Add the full error message to your question. **3)** Look at [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22002636/522444).

Comment: Thanks Sir. I edited my this "first" question.

Comment: **Many** thanks for the updated information. Check your Eclipse Build path. Please also look at [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464592/getting-the-following-build-error-the-type-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-ind).

Comment: Sorry if we "sound" rude, it's just we're voluntiers and don't get paid for this. So time is important. All we want is that you help us to help you.

Comment: Ya thanks.. my path is correct. if you are asking the path from "My Computer/Settings/Variable Environment" then it is correct.

Comment: David, no, I think that your problem may be related to how Eclipse has been set up, which is why I've added an Eclipse tag to your question. The build path is a path that eclipse uses to find the necessary files needed to run your programs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "import" classes in each file in order to use them.

You have imported `JPanel` but not `JComponent`.

Under your import `JPanel` line add another one that looks the same but has `JComponent` at the end instead of `JPanel`.

Comment: how to import classes in each file Sir?

Comment: @DavidStevenson you go to each class and do the import as TimB said.

Comment: I edited question. Please review, i mentioned classes. thanks