# The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java

I'm getting this error:

> The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required .class files

How do I resolve it? Below is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class Hello {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello");
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29901132/jpanel-error-j-component-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: but hey i can't solve the problem with the answer given in that topic, feel bad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java project in Eclipse: The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18075343/java-project-in-eclipse-the-type-java-lang-object-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-ind)

Comment: I'm sorry , i've tried everything they told me to do but noting seems work , i can't fix this error @Mingebag

Comment: Which buildsystem (maven, gradle) and which IDE (Eclipse, IntelliJ) do you use?

Comment: Go there ,it is **already answered** <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582102/java-swing-component-cannot-be-resolved/>

Answer (score 0):

Probably this problem arises from eclipse. When i have this problem i was using *Eclipse Helios* (Helios is an old version.). Then **downloaded *Eclipse Oxygen*** (newest version) and ran project, problem solved. Your problem looks very like much mine. Good Luck.

Comment: you got `The type javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved` error?

Comment: Just download new version isn't really an answer

Comment: This is a real solution guys. This problem is an eclipse bug. [look this document](http://dev-answers.blogspot.com.tr/2009/06/eclipse-build-errors-javalangobject.html) And if the matter is a bug, best way is delete&install, close&open... This is computer. And if i solved this problem with my way. This is a kind of solution. I hope my solution helping people who have got this problem.